# DateTime constant checking if null

Tags: php, datetime

So it seems I constantly run into this. When I get the date from the db I'm not sure if it's set so I end up doing this:

```
$myObject->setDate($row['theDate'] ? new DateTime($row['theDate']) : null);
```

and when I need to retrieve that date in a form

```
echo '<input value=" ',$myObject->getDate() ? $myObject->getDate()->format('d-m-Y') : null ,'">';
```

and when I go to save it back in the DB

```
$s->bindValue(':myDate', $myObject->getDate() ? $myObject->getDate()->format('Y-m-d') : null);
```

This constant checking to me seems crazy and when that happens it usually means I'm doing something wrong. Is there a flaw in the way I'm using Datetime or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You can move these checks inside `getDate`/`setDate`

Comment: I could in the first example, but not the next 2 since I'm calling format

Comment: And what is wrong with passing format as parameter to `getDate`?

Comment: Well.....I don't know. So would I make the format parameter optional and if the parameter contains a value return the formatted value and if not return the DateTime object?

Comment: I would make separate function like `getDateObject` and always return string/null from `getDate`

Comment: It seems that if I have 1-6 dates per object and 12 objects that contain dates that would be a lot of extra methods. Not to mention all the extra checking in the setDate method. It would seem to violate DRY or maybe I'm over thinking this.